# Send data from 2 fragments to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments and I have to send data from fragment n1 and fragment n2 to the third fragment.
The sequence of fragments is:
1->2
2->3.

Comment: you can use bundle. setArgument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply , you can use bundle to pass data from fragment to another fragment like that

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        msubcategories.setArguments(bundle);
        bundle.putString("data", data);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in Fragment2 you can get data

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        assert bundle != null;
      String  data = bundle.getString("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared ViewModel scoped to the activity lifecycle and use it to share the data between the fragments.

Code from the docs:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    fun select(item: Item) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}

class MasterFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener { item ->
            // Update the UI
        }
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        model.selected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Item> { item ->
            // Update the UI
        })
    }
}
```

See more here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing